# Trouble with Installation on Acer Aspire One Cloudbook 14. "Kernel panic - not syncing: IO-APIC + timer doesn't work"

Tags: boot, kernel, uefi, laptop, acer

I recently bought a new laptop (Acer Aspire One Cloudbook 14) and wanted to install Ubuntu (14.04.3) on it. I put it on a USB following this guide: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

I erased Windows 10 and installed Ubuntu. I honestly don't remember how the installation initially went as I have been trying to fix this issue for over 12 hours, I know it didn't go too smoothly, as I remember the screen showed a few errors during installation but it eventually loaded, and other than the touch pad not working, it seemed fine.

On the reboot however, I was unable to even log in.

**BOOT MODE: LEGACY**

If I have the boot mode set to Legacy, it takes me to a GNU Grub thing if my hard drive is highest priority in boot order, listing a few options (see the picture bellow).

[image: boot legacy]

If I select Ubuntu, that is when I get the messed up screen and **"Kernel panic - not syncing: IO-APIC + timer doesn't work"** error.

If I have USB as highest priority (again in Legacy mode) it takes me to the installation menu, though I suspect it doesn't look the way it is suppose to, but that's how it looked when I first installed it, the difference now is, whether I select install Ubuntu or try without installing, I get the same **kernel panic** error I mentioned earlier.

[image: kernel panic error legacy]

**BOOT MODE: UEFI**

If I run it in UEFI mode, it says **"No bootable device"** whether my hard drive (or whatever the equivalent is on this laptop) or USB is priority.

[image: boot UEFI]

I believe I installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode by accident, which maybe caused this issue?

I have been searching online for many hours, but could not find an issue that was close enough to mine, and already tried many of the solutions of problems that were similar. Like disabling secure boot, trying different boot modes, and nothing is listed if I try to select a trusted UEFI file when hard drive is priority, if USB is priority, it just lists files that are on the USB, none of which can be selected.

Laptop Specs: 
 
Intel® Celeron® N3050 processor Dual-core 1.60 GHz 
Intel® HD Graphics with Shared Memory 
2 GB, DDR3L SDRAM 
32 GB Flash Memory

Comment: If Windows is installed in EFI/UEFI mode, you should *not* install Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. I recommend you *disable* the CSM (aka "legacy boot support" or a similar phrase) in the firmware and re-install. That said, the problem you're reporting is most likely not caused by BIOS-mode vs. EFI-mode issues; it's most likely caused by driver problems. It *might* be fixed by using a more recent kernel, which in the case of Ubuntu, means a more recent release. Try 14.04.4 or even a 16.04 beta instead of 14.04.3.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am downloading 14.04.4 now and will try to install that. Not sure how I am going to do it out of legacy mode though, as my computer cannot seem to read the USB if it is not in legacy mode, and my laptop doesn't have a disk drive, so can't use a CD. Any ideas? I will try to figure it out in the mean time, hopefully it reads the USB now, not expecting it to, but I sure am hoping. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Well it was able to boot from the USB. It takes me to a black screen with the following options: 1) Try Ubuntu w/o installing 2) Install Ubuntu 3) OEM Install 4) Check Disc for Defects.     When I enter install Ubuntu the screen just stays black. I am now researching how to fix that, already tried adding nomodset after quiet splash in 'commands before booting'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have booted in legacy mode, installed via USB, and are now trying to boot up your freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04. then:

The correct boot alteration as detailed [here in the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acer_Cloudbook)

Is to add the following parameters to the file `/etc/default/grub` in the line that begins `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet edd=off noapic modprobe.blacklist=pinctrl_cherryview"
```

After changing this file, to make the changes effective, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

This worked for installing Ubuntu 14.04

If having trouble booting up initially, press <kbd>e</kbd> at the boot options (GRUB) menu and add the parameters at the end of the line with `quiet splash`:

```
edd=off noapic modprobe.blacklist=pinctrl_cherryview
```

I have bought  the Acer Cloudbook 14 and installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it.

Answer (score 0):

(READ LAST UPDATE) 
I finally got Ubuntu running! I actually had a couple more errors, that are not in this thread, but I put up a more detailed post of my experience here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317336

The Steps I took to install Ubuntu and resolve this issue: 
1) Reinstalled Windows 10 
2) Turned off fast start up in the power options menu in Windows 
3) Change Boot Order in BIOS to boot from USB ( I also changed touchpad settings 
 for my laptop to basic from advanced, but this may not be necessary) 
4) Try Ubuntu Without Installing 
5) Clicked Install when on Ubuntu Desktop 
6) I replaced Windows 10, but this is up to you 
7) Restarted, removed USB and Changed boot order so my hard drive was priority  again 
8) I actually got the 'No Bootable Disk' error again, my heart sank, BUT this time I was able to select a trusted UEFI file as shown on this website: http://itsfoss.com/no-bootable-device-found-ubuntu/

That's it! What I learned from this, try before you install to see how it runs on your computer, and have a backup of whatever OS you were using before in case.

LAST UPDATE: 
Okay, I spoke too soon. I was having issues with getting stuck on a purple screen when the computer would start, it would successfully log in 1/10 times, and after following these instructions: [Ubuntu 14.04 loads to purple screen on Lenovo G505s. nomodeset wont work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451638/ubuntu-14-04-loads-to-purple-screen-on-lenovo-g505s-nomodeset-wont-work/) from Taz D (the one about installing xubuntu desktop), that number went up to around 1/5, but I was not satisfied with that and after trying many other solutions online, and trying to install Xubuntu on it, I just gave up and traded laptops with my fiance. She has an HP 15, don't know the particular model. The installation on that laptop went pretty flawless, only thing that slowed me down was I did not know I had to click F9 when it was booting to select a boot device in order to access the USB.